# Webpack: load js modules dynamically from a URL at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, require, remote-server

I am currently working on a library which should dynamically load a JavaScript from a remote host and instantiate that.

I am writing the library in TypeScript and my plan is to use Webpack as a bundler.

On another host (remote system) runs a provider which should serve JavaScript code (see here: https://stubs.d-koppenhagen.de/stubs/SimpleStub.js).
The library will dynamically resolve "Identitys" via Webfinger. These Identitys represented by an object and they having a property pointing to a "Stub Provider" which will serve JavaScript code (the link I mentioned before). My library should load this script during runtime (s the library don't know the target for this stubs before) and should use it.

currently my webpack.config.js looks like the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
};

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    wonder: PATHS.src + '/wonder'
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'Wonder',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin()
  ]
};
```

And here is a part of the library code:

```
require.ensure([], function() {
  require(localMsgStubUrl);
});
```

When I am now including the bundled library in an example app, I will get the following error: 
[Error: loading chunk failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkZMR.png)

So is there a way to tell webpack not to bundle the code which is required from a external resource loaded from a URL so that I can use that code like it is?

I don't want to tell webpack the URL statically in a config as maybe other stubs I am loading are located on a different target.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can tell webpack to use externals.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
When you do this webpack does not load the libraries from a url you specified instead it expects them to already be in the browser context and included with <script> tags.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, probably this is what I need but I still have the same error. I added the following to my webpack.config.js:  `externals: { MessagingStub: 'MessagingStub' } ` 
(for loading again e.g.: https://stubs.d-koppenhagen.de/stubs/SimpleStub.js )? Do I miss something necessary?

Comment: I see your issue. The SimpleStub.js file is formatted for commonjs however it is being loaded directly into the browser. Note the references to an exports object. I don't know the correct way to handle this but a quick hack would be to define ```exports={}``` above your script in the webpage and then use `{MessagingStub:"exports"}`.

Comment: I think it's no what i need. I tried it out but it doesn't have any effect. I changed the remote module now to amd resolution to be sure that webpack can handle this (as described here it should: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ ). I think the problem is that webpack still tries to bunle the remote file even after I added `externals: { MessagingStub: 'MessagingStub' }` to my webpack.config.js. So do you have any clue why webpack seems to ignore this? I am still getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkZMR.png) error.